# Can anyone offer a full example of django-haystack with solr 5.x?

Tags: python, django, solr

Trying to find an example of how to build an application using solr 5.x with django-haystack, but most examples online are using solr 4.x or solr 3.x. Can anyone give some instructions on how to work with solr 5.x using django-haystack, or just offer some example project? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Django-Haystack does not support SOLR 5 well.  SOLR 5's **solrconfig.xml** file for its core uses `ManagedIndexSchemaFactory` as default `schemaFactory`. If you change it to `ClassicIndexSchemaFactory`, you will run in troubles with your **schema.xml** which is generated by `python manage.py build_solr_schema`. Lots of fields' types are not supported. Probably going back to SOLR 4 would be a better choice